# How to cleanly "close"/"abort" a websocket connection *before* it connects

Tags: javascript, websocket, browser, browser-console, abortcontroller

I am making a ws connection, but in some cases I need/want to abort the request cleanly, without the console logging an error like this one -

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://xyz:3001/? failed: WebSocket is closed
> before the connection is established.

the code looks like:

```
const ws = new WebSocket(`${url}`);

setTimeout(() => ws.close(), random); // some other event that occur at any given time "random"
```

A simple use case is if a connection is initiated when a user opens a view, but then quickly closes the view which could/should abort the connection request.

is there a way to abort the connection request cleanly, so that I don't get too many logs like that in the browser console?

Comment: You may want to refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#connection_errors for how to handle these scenarios.

Comment: just looked, don't see an answer there boss, do you?

Comment: If you just want to avoid the warnings in the console, you could always wait for the connection to established before closing it.

Comment: sure but there might be a good optimization if we have a million clients doing the same thing -

Comment: If that's a problem, also consider debouncing the connections requests (i.e. open the connection only after a small delay) or even keeping a single connection alive instead repeatedly opening and closing a new connection for every view. But I don't mean to devalue your question, this is a reasonable problem worthy of a proper solution - I only suggested my workaround in a comment not as an answer.

Comment: well, there is an abortcontroller for regular https reqs, there should be one for ws requests too

Comment: There's none for `XMLHttpRequest` either - and `WebSocket` is older than `fetch`. You may want to consider [proposing to add that as an option](https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues), though

Comment: ok, I did - https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/57

Answer (score 1):

You can test and see if the [`readyState`](https://websockets.spec.whatwg.org/#websocket-ready-state) property could help.

You can use it to check the connection's current state before attempting to close it. That would allow you to avoid trying to close the connection if it is not in an open state, thus preventing the error message from appearing in the console.

The WebSocket API provides different states through the `readyState` attribute:

- `CONNECTING` (0): The connection is not yet open.
- `OPEN` (1): The connection is open and ready to communicate.
- `CLOSING` (2): The connection is in the process of closing.
- `CLOSED` (3): The connection is closed or could not be opened.

You can use these states to decide when it is appropriate to close the WebSocket:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket(`${url}`);

setTimeout(() => {
    // Check if the WebSocket's state is CONNECTING or OPEN before attempting to close it
    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING || ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        ws.close();
    }
}, random); // some other event that occur at any given time "random"
```

That code modification makes sure `ws.close()` is only called if the WebSocket is either still connecting or already open. If the WebSocket is in the process of closing or is already closed, calling `close()` again can lead to unwanted errors or logs.

> I am 99% sure that calling `ws.close() when ws.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING`, will log an error in the console, I just want to effectively remove the local listener and drop to the void

Given the limitations of the WebSocket API in handling this specific use case directly, you might consider using a flag to prevent actions on early closure.

```js
let proceedWithConnection = true;

const ws = new WebSocket(`${url}`);

// Set up WebSocket event listeners
ws.onopen = () => {
    if (!proceedWithConnection) {
        ws.close(); // Close immediately if we have decided not to proceed
    } else {
        // Proceed with setting up the connection
    }
};

// Some other event that might occur at any given time
setTimeout(() => {
    proceedWithConnection = false;
}, random);
```

Or you could delay the actual connection attempt until you are more certain you will need it. That could involve setting up a preliminary delay (debouncing the connection attempt, as previously discussed) to make sure the user's action necessitates the WebSocket connection:

```js
let shouldConnect = true;

setTimeout(() => {
    if (shouldConnect) {
        const ws = new WebSocket(`${url}`);
        // Set up your WebSocket connection here
    }
}, delayBeforeConnecting);

// Some event indicates the connection should not proceed
setTimeout(() => {
    shouldConnect = false;
}, random);
```

---

That also ties in with the OP's [`whatwg/websockets` issue 57](https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/57), where [Adam Rice  (`ricea`)](https://github.com/ricea), from the Chromium project, adds:

> The WebSocket `close()` method can already be used to do this. If you don't like Chrome's behaviour of printing a console message when this happens you should file an issue at https://crbug.com/.
>
> The [proposed WebSocketStream API](https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/pull/48) uses [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) for cancelling the handshake already.
>
> We are unlikely to add this to the WebSocket API because it can be easily emulated with a function like
>
> ```js
> function AbortableWebSocket(url, signal) {
>   signal.throwIfAborted();
>   const ws = new WebSocket(url);
>   const abortHandler = () => ws.close();
>   signal.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler);
>   ws.addEventListener('open', 
>     () => signal.removeEventListener('abort', abortHandler));
>   return ws;
> }
> ```

So the [`signal.throwIfAborted()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal/throwIfAborted) call will make sure that, if the operation was already aborted before the WebSocket connection was initiated, it would immediately throw, preventing the connection.
If the abort event is signaled after the connection attempt has started but before it is fully open, it calls `ws.close()` to terminate the attempt. Once the connection is successfully opened, it removes the abort event listener to clean up resources.

But, as noted by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971834/how-to-cleanly-close-abort-a-websocket-connection-before-it-connects/77981695#comment137518169_77981695), using `ws.close()` to terminate a WebSocket connection attempt that has not fully opened could still lead to a warning in the developer console.
That is precisely the situation you were aiming to avoid, as the goal is to abort the connection attempt silently, without generating console warnings.

You might consider a slightly different approach, focusing on preventing the connection attempt from proceeding or being initiated based on the abort signal, rather than trying to close an already initiated connection.
However, this approach has limitations because, once a WebSocket connection attempt is made, the API does not provide a built-in, silent abort mechanism.

You can modify Adam Rice's code to integrate the abort logic in a way that minimizes the chances of generating console warnings. You woud introduce a check before initiating the WebSocket connection to make sure the abort signal has not been triggered. And modify the cleanup process to make sure resources are released without necessarily closing the WebSocket connection if it is still in the `CONNECTING` state.
Instead of closing the WebSocket upon abort, manage the state to prevent further actions on the WebSocket if it is not yet open.

```js
function AbortableWebSocket(url, signal) {
    // Immediately abort if the signal has already been triggered
    if (signal.aborted) {
        console.log("WebSocket connection aborted before initiation.");
        return null; // Or handle this case as appropriate for your application
    }

    const ws = new WebSocket(url);
    let aborted = false; // Track if the connection has been aborted

    const abortHandler = () => {
        console.log("Abort signal received.");
        aborted = true;
        // Instead of calling ws.close(), which can log a warning, manage abort state locally
    };

    signal.addEventListener('abort', abortHandler);

    // Cleanup function to remove all listeners and handle abort state
    const cleanup = () => {
        signal.removeEventListener('abort', abortHandler);
        ws.removeEventListener('open', onOpen);
        ws.removeEventListener('error', onError);
        ws.removeEventListener('close', onClose);

        if (aborted) {
            // Handle any necessary cleanup or state management due to aborting
            console.log("WebSocket connection cleanup after abort.");
        }
    };

    const onOpen = () => {
        if (aborted) {
            // Close the connection only if it is fully open and abort was requested
            ws.close();
        }
        cleanup();
    };

    const onError = () => cleanup();
    const onClose = () => cleanup();

    ws.addEventListener('open', onOpen);
    ws.addEventListener('error', onError);
    ws.addEventListener('close', onClose);

    return ws;
}
```

Comment: I am 99% sure that calling ws.close() when ws.readyState === WebSocket.CONNECTING, will log an error in the console, I just want to effectively remove the local listener and drop to the void

Comment: it's lookin good

Comment: I don't see how your final snippet solves the problem. "*If the abort event is signaled after the connection attempt has started but before it is fully open, it calls `ws.close()` to terminate the attempt.*" - and that will again cause the devtools to log a warning, no?

Comment: @Bergi True, I have included your comment in the answer, and proposed a modified approach.

Comment: Seems like a good API to be made native

Comment: @AlexanderMills I agree. From what I can see, it is not yet a native function.